# How to share an image on Instagram in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, instagram-api

My client wants to share an image on Instagram, Twitter, Facebook.

I have done Twitter and Facebook but did not find any API or any thing on internet to share image on Instagram. **Is it possible to share image on Instagram? if yes then how?**

When I check the developer site of Instagram I have found the Libraries of Ruby on Rails and Python. But there are no documentation of iOS Sdk

I have get token from instagram as per instagram.com/developer but now don't know what to do next step for sharing with instagram image.

Comment: Any idea on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858512/instagram-ios-hooks-getting-the-posted-media-id-back?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. you can not directly post an image on instagram. You have to rediredt your image with UIDocumentInteractionController.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *dic;    

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.igo"];

NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];
self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];


- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {
     UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
     interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
     return interactionController;
}
```

**NOTE :** once you redirect to instagram app you can not back to your app. you have to open your app again

Download source from [here](https://github.com/hiren443/InstagramShareiOS)

Comment: where is the function setupControllerWithURL or it do ?

Comment: hey i have used your code.. it opens a actionsheet with "instagram" option but when i click on that nothing happens..can you please help me

Comment: @SurenderRathore you have to scale your image into into 612*612 and save into .ig format .ig shows that you want to open your image into instagram and you have to test in your iPhone or iPod upto version 4.3 . iPad is not supported

Comment: How can I get followers list from Instagram?

Comment: @HiRen: Thanks, it is working well. Now I want to share some text also with image like we do in facebook and twitter. How can I do this for instagram?

Comment: @user2135853 If you are using this code then you are already moved to native instagram app. So you can use all the functionality of app

Comment: @HiRen: Yes, you are right but in my app I am taking screenshot of a view and and then sharing that screenshot via instagram app and its perfectly working well. But I also want to pass some static text with that screenshot. If you have any idea please help me. There is a demo code on github for DMACtivityInstagram and you can see from there what I m trying to say. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HiRen:Did u find anything on how to share text with image on instagram with this code? Thanks...

Comment: @HiRen: I got my answer. Added the line below and it worked for me. self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Here write what you want to share" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

Comment: @HiRen: I am opening Instagram from my app for sharing and it works fine. But Is it possible that Can I check Whether the user has shared it successfully or not? Means I want to perform some action in my DB when user successfully shares an image. How can i do this?

Comment: @ManthanPatel this is not possible because once you redirect to Instagram you can not come back to your app. If you want this then you can get images from Instagram and check if image is in the list then change the status in DB

Comment: @NSNull: Is it possible that if we click on a button and it directly navigates me to the native instagram app? You can see what I want from the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954810/remove-activityviewcontroller-when-sharing-in-ios6/16955128?noredirect=1#16955128]

Comment: once i redirect to instagram app i can not back my app is right ? or possible to back my app Please reply me

Comment: Yes once you redirect to instagram you can not back to your app.

Comment: Is there a way to get Instagram's post_id of what the user just shared?

Comment: @sabir post new question in SO. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559518/fetching-user-profile-data-from-linkedin-in-iphone-sdk. I have never worked on LinkedIn API.

Comment: hi @Hiren i have done the linked in can you please share me how can i get complete profile information from instragram..

Comment: @sabir please read the docs of instagram. It will help to you a lot. http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: Using this line gave me a crash in iOS 6: NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

Using this works in both: NSURL *igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jpgPath];

Might be worth editing the answer accordingly, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @weienw, While I came to comment, you have already mentioned it.

Comment: is this jus me, or does anyone else wants to say "hey Instagram, you were developer once, why are you making our life this hard?"

Answer (score 27):

**Here is a full tested code to Upload image + caption text to Instagram..**

**in.h file**

```
//Instagram
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController;

-(void)instaGramWallPost
{
            NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
            if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) //check for App is install or not
            {
                NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imge); //convert image into .png format.
                NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
                NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insta.igo"]]; //add our image to the path
                [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)
                NSLog(@"image saved");

                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
                [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                NSString *fileNameToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/insta.igo"];
                NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameToSave];
                NSLog(@"jpg path %@",jpgPath);
                NSString *newJpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath];
                NSLog(@"with File path %@",newJpgPath);
                NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:newJpgPath];
                NSLog(@"url Path %@",igImageHookFile);

                self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
                self.documentController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
                self.documentController=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
                NSString *caption = @"#Your Text"; //settext as Default Caption
                self.documentController.annotation=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",caption],@"InstagramCaption", nil];
                [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView: self.view animated:YES];
            }
            else
            {
                 NSLog (@"Instagram not found");
            }
}

- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {
    NSLog(@"file url %@",fileURL);
    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

    return interactionController;
}
```

**OR**

```
-(void)instaGramWallPost
{
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your image url"];
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    UIImage *imgShare = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) //check for App is install or not
    {
        UIImage *imageToUse = imgShare;
        NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.igo"];
        NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUse);
        [imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
        NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];
        self.documentController=[[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc]init];
        self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
        self.documentController.delegate = self;
        self.documentController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing"], @"InstagramCaption", nil];
        self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
        UIViewController *vc = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1) inView:vc.view animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        DisplayAlertWithTitle(@"Instagram not found", @"")
    }
}
```

**and Write this to .plist**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: is it possible to come back to application after image share on Instagram ?

Comment: no... we have to come back manually... but if i found any solution i will update code...

Comment: I choose the Instagram button but nothing happens after that? Is there some additional code beyond this answer to do that?

Comment: Instagram Application is install in your device?

Comment: Is it possible to get 'media-id' in this case?

Comment: i think no because Instagram leave the app to upload the pic and use the native app for further process so..

Comment: Yeah @Gamechanger, You are correct. Any ways you know to share other than 'UIDocumentInteractionController'?. I'm searching for the approach to get 'media-id' instantly after sharing from my app.

Comment: if i will found any solution then i will inform you.

Comment: Thanks @Gamechanger.

Comment: @HectorOllison Hm, looks like it doesn't work in iOS 10. Can you check?

Comment: @HardikThakkar i check in ios 10 and it is working fine but only one problem coming that caption is not pre populate.is there any reason for it.

Comment: Do you give any predefined text?

Comment: @HardikThakkar when I use your solution I get only selection of apps to choose, not Instagram. IOS 11. Do you know if it works still? Thank you

Comment: Please try when Instagram app is install in device.

Answer (score 24):

You can use one of the provided by Instagram url scheme

[image]

1. Instagram [oficial doc here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/)
2. Share with UIDocumentInteractionController

   ```
    final class InstagramPublisher : NSObject {

    private var documentsController:UIDocumentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

    func postImage(image: UIImage, view: UIView, result:((Bool)->Void)? = nil) {
        guard let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app") else {
            if let result = result {
                result(false)
            }
        return
    }
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
            let jpgPath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("instagrammFotoToShareName.igo")
            if let image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
                image.writeToFile(jpgPath, atomically: true)
                let fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(jpgPath)
                documentsController.URL = fileURL
                documentsController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
                documentsController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(view.bounds, inView: view, animated: true)
                if let result = result {
                    result(true)
                }
            } else if let result = result {
                result(false)
            }
        } else {
            if let result = result {
                result(false)
            }
        }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Share with direct redirect

   ```
    import Photos

    final class InstagramPublisher : NSObject {

    func postImage(image: UIImage, result:((Bool)->Void)? = nil) {
    guard let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app") else {
        if let result = result {
            result(false)
        }
        return
    }

    let image = image.scaleImageWithAspectToWidth(640)

    do {
        try PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChangesAndWait {
            let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)

            let assetID = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset?.localIdentifier ?? ""
            let shareURL = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + assetID

            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
                if let urlForRedirect = NSURL(string: shareURL) {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(urlForRedirect)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        if let result = result {
            result(false)
        }
    }
    }
    }
   ```
4. extension for resize photo to recommended size

   ```
    import UIKit

    extension UIImage {
        // MARK: - UIImage+Resize

        func scaleImageWithAspectToWidth(toWidth:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
            let oldWidth:CGFloat = size.width
            let scaleFactor:CGFloat = toWidth / oldWidth

            let newHeight = self.size.height * scaleFactor
            let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
            drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return newImage
        }
    }
   ```
5. Don't forget to add required scheme in plist

> ```
>   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
>   <array>
>        <string>instagram</string> 
>   </array>
> ```

Comment: Tried a bunch of other stuff from other answers and only this worked (at least for videos. The "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" was what did it. Many thanks!

Comment: The share with direct redirect (which is by far the best solution IMO) no longer works for me - Instagram opens at the library page but doesn't pre-select an image. Does you have any idea what might have changed with this URL scheme? Are you experiencing similar failures with the latest version of Instagram on iOS?

Comment: @gbk This code works for me. But I have new requirement sahre multiple photos in  Instagram. Like Instagram have new option multiple upload and display like slide view. 
Do you how to do this? Please help me.

Comment: Holy sh*t. Thank you for this. I've been banging my head against a wall for the past day trying to get sharing to instagram from my app to work nicely.

Comment: @gbk, I did. :)

Comment: only 3'd variant is working for me for ios 13, btw dont forget to add <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>App needs your nude photos.</string>

Answer (score 14):

Hope this answer will resolve your query. This will directly opens library folder in Instagram instead of Camera.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{
    NSURL *videoFilePath = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[request downloadDestinationPath]]]; // Your local path to the video
    NSString *caption = @"Some Preloaded Caption";
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoFilePath completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        NSString *escapedString   = [self urlencodedString:videoFilePath.absoluteString];
        NSString *escapedCaption  = [self urlencodedString:caption];
        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",escapedString,escapedCaption]];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Do find that every time you do this, Instagram app will load select the previous image? I think theres something wrong with the asset path link.

Comment: excellent!!So Instagram can be open Directly without UIDocumentInteractionController.Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me with this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226433/instagram-hooks-pre-select-media-issue

Comment: Can we also pass the URL too with image?

Comment: Unfortunately, ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated since iOS 9.

Answer (score 10):

if you don't want to use UIDocumentInteractionController

```
import Photos

...

func postImageToInstagram(image: UIImage) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(SocialShare.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }
    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions)
        if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
            let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
            let u = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
            let url = NSURL(string: u)!
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: u)!)
            } else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Instagram is not installed", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It's what I really need. Thanks!

Comment: You saved my life, Perfect answer. Thanks !!

Comment: This is totally wrong every time when i click to share on instagram & did cancel its saving to camera roll.

Answer (score 9):

For iOS 6 and above, you can use this UIActivity to upload images to Instagram which has the same workflow using iOS hooks but simplifies development:

https://github.com/coryalder/DMActivityInstagram

Comment: hi @Chintan Patel how can i get user profile information in if you have any sample source please share with us

Answer (score 6):

this is correct answer which i implement with detail.
    In .h file

```
 UIImageView *imageMain;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController;
```

in.m file only write

```
 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
 if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
 {
      CGFloat cropVal = (imageMain.image.size.height > imageMain.image.size.width ? imageMain.image.size.width : imageMain.image.size.height);

      cropVal *= [imageMain.image scale];

      CGRect cropRect = (CGRect){.size.height = cropVal, .size.width = cropVal};
      CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageMain.image CGImage], cropRect);

      NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef], 1.0);
      CGImageRelease(imageRef);

      NSString *writePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instagram.igo"];
      if (![imageData writeToFile:writePath atomically:YES]) {
      // failure
           NSLog(@"image save failed to path %@", writePath);
           return;
      } else {
      // success.
      }

      // send it to instagram.
      NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:writePath];
      self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
      self.documentController.delegate = self;
      [self.documentController setUTI:@"com.instagram.exclusivegram"];
      [self.documentController setAnnotation:@{@"InstagramCaption" : @"We are making fun"}];
      [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) inView:self.view animated:YES];
 }
 else
 {
      NSLog (@"Instagram not found");

 }
```

For sure you will get result. E.g you will see popover from bottom with instagram image.Click on it and have fun.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this in my application and it is working perfectly (Swift)

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class InstagramManager: NSObject, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    private let kInstagramURL = "instagram://"
    private let kUTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
    private let kfileNameExtension = "instagram.igo"
    private let kAlertViewTitle = "Error"
    private let kAlertViewMessage = "Please install the Instagram application"

    var documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

    // singleton manager
    class var sharedManager: InstagramManager {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = InstagramManager()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    func postImageToInstagramWithCaption(imageInstagram: UIImage, instagramCaption: String, view: UIView) {
        // called to post image with caption to the instagram application

        let instagramURL = NSURL(string: kInstagramURL)
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!) {
            let jpgPath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(kfileNameExtension)
            UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageInstagram, 1.0)!.writeToFile(jpgPath, atomically: true)
            let rect = CGRectMake(0,0,612,612)
            let fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(jpgPath)
            documentInteractionController.URL = fileURL
            documentInteractionController.delegate = self
            documentInteractionController.UTI = kUTI

            // adding caption for the image
            documentInteractionController.annotation = ["InstagramCaption": instagramCaption]
            documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(rect, inView: view, animated: true)
        }
        else {

            // alert displayed when the instagram application is not available in the device
            UIAlertView(title: kAlertViewTitle, message: kAlertViewMessage, delegate:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"Ok").show()
        }
    }
}


 func sendToInstagram(){

     let image = postImage

             InstagramManager.sharedManager.postImageToInstagramWithCaption(image!, instagramCaption: "\(description)", view: self.view)

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct answer. you cannot directly post an image on Instagram. You need to redirect to Instagram using UIDocumentInteractionController...

```
NSString* imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/instagramShare.igo", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];
    
UIImage *instagramImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename you want to share"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(instagramImage) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"Image Size >>> %@", NSStringFromCGSize(instagramImage.size));
    
self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
self.dic.delegate = self;
self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES ];
```

**NOTE :** once you redirect to instagram app you can not back to your app. you have to open your app again

Comment: You set the delegate but didn't write it / post it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without using the UIDocumentInteractionController and go straight to Instagram with these 3 methods:

It works just like all the other famous app does.
The code is written in Objective c, so you can translate it to swift if you want.
What you need to do is saving your image to the device and use a URLScheme

add this inside your .m file

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
```

First you need to save your UIImage to the device with this method:

```
-(void)savePostsPhotoBeforeSharing
{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageNamed:@"image_file_name.jpg"], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
}
```

This method is the callback for saving the image to your device:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
{
    [self sharePostOnInstagram];

}
```

After the image is saved to the device, you need to query the image you just saved and get it as a PHAsset

```
-(void)sharePostOnInstagram
{
    PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO],];
    __block PHAsset *assetToShare;
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
    [result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        assetToShare = asset;


    }];


    if([assetToShare isKindOfClass:[PHAsset class]])
    {
        NSString *localIdentifier = assetToShare.localIdentifier;
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=%@",localIdentifier];
        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: instagramURL])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: instagramURL];
        } else
        {
            // can not share with whats app
            NSLog(@"No instagram installed");
        }

    }
}
```

And dont forget to put this in your info.plist under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

```
<string>instagram</string>
```

Comment: How can I add multiple photos on instagram?

Answer (score 2):

```
    @import Photos;

    -(void)shareOnInstagram:(UIImage*)imageInstagram {

        [self authorizePHAssest:imageInstagram];
    }

    -(void)authorizePHAssest:(UIImage *)aImage{

        PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];

        if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            // Access has been granted.
            [self savePostsPhotoBeforeSharing:aImage];
        }

        else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
            // Access has been denied.
        }

        else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

            // Access has not been determined.
            [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {

                if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
                    // Access has been granted.
                    [self savePostsPhotoBeforeSharing:aImage];
                }
            }];
        }

        else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
            // Restricted access - normally won't happen.
        }
    }
    -(void)saveImageInDeviceBeforeSharing:(UIImage *)aImage
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(aImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
    }

    - (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
    {
        if (error == nil){
            [self sharePostOnInstagram];
        }
    }

    -(void)shareImageOnInstagram
    {
        PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:false]];
        PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];

        __block PHAsset *assetToShare = [result firstObject];

        if([assetToShare isKindOfClass:[PHAsset class]])
        {
            NSString *localIdentifier = assetToShare.localIdentifier;
            NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=%@",localIdentifier];
            NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: instagramURL])
            {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
            } else
            {
                NSLog(@"No instagram installed");
            }
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:- 
    IMP TODO:- Add below key in Info.plist**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

Comment: The only problem with this is, that if the user has set ```limited``` photo library access, it won't show the latest image, instead the Instagram will show the latest image out of all the images that the user has selected or allowed before via the photo library view controller thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) shareImageWithInstagram
{
    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
    {
        UICachedFileMgr* mgr = _gCachedManger;
        UIImage* photoImage = [mgr imageWithUrl:_imageView.image];
        NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photoImage);
        NSString* captionString = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"ANY_TAG",];
        NSString* imagePath = [UIUtils documentDirectoryWithSubpath:@"image.igo"];
        [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];
        NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",imagePath]];

        self.docFile = [[self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL usingDelegate:self]retain];
        self.docFile.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: captionString
                                                     forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
        self.docFile.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";

        // OPEN THE HOOK
        [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [UIUtils messageAlert:@"Instagram not installed in this device!\nTo share image please install instagram." title:nil delegate:nil];
    }
}
```

I tried this in my application and it will definitely work

Comment: Maybe you should explain `UIUtils` & `UICachedFileMgr`?

Comment: Understand. Suggest to edit your answer to provide more details

Comment: @Raptor:
Please download the sample app from the following:

[link](https://github.com/sinha-neha/iOSHUB/tree/PostToIGSample)

Comment: UIUtils is a class that I have created in order to manage utility methods.It is derived from NSObject. I have added the messageAlert method to show the alert view. In the sample app whose link I have provided above, you can find UIUtils class. Hopefully, you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, the best and the easiest way described here [Share photo to Instagram from my iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297157/share-photo-to-instagram-from-my-ios-app)

You need to save image on device using .igo format, then use "UIDocumentInteractionController" to send local path Instagram app. Don't forget to set "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate"

My advice is to add something like:

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) 
{
 <your code>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{

    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/Insta_Images/%@",@"shareImage.png"]];


    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];


    docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";

    docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];

    docController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];

    docController.delegate=self;

    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 612, 612) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed if you put `URL` pointing to image to `activityItems` instead of `UIImage`, `Copy to Instagram` activity item appears itself, and you don't have to do anything else. Please note that `String` objects inside `activityItems` would be discarded and there is no way to prefill caption in Instagram. If you still want to hint user to post particular caption, you'd need to create custom activity where you copy that text to clipboard and let user know about it, like in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/almassapargali/109fe4145e01f9df272307eb9447b2b4).

Answer (score 0):

I Used this code:

```
    NSString* filePathStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UMS_social_demo" ofType:@"png"];
NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathStr];

NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.igo"];
[[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl] writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

NSURL* documentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: documentURL];
self.interactionController = interactionController;
interactionController.delegate = self;
interactionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
[interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)shareOnInstagram {

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.375 ,self.view.frame.size.height/2 , 0, 0);



    NSString * saveImagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/ShareInstragramImage.igo"];

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image) writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];

    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", saveImagePath]];

    self.documentController=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];

    self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    self.documentController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];

    [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];

}

-(UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
    return interactionController;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:sampleImageURL];
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
UIImage *imageToUse = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];
[imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];
self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
self.documentController.delegate = self;
self.documentController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""], @"", nil];
self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
[self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```