# Fetching user profile data from LinkedIn in iPhone sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, linkedin-api

Using IOS, I am trying to integrate the LinkedIn into the application.
The integration is also working,user login is also working but the I am not able to fetch the data of user profile with all records of user as Education,Skills and all.
I am able to get only these four values after successful login.
    -first-name
    -site-standard-profile-request
    -last-name
    -headline

Can anyone please to get all the values rather than these.
Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question was to get the profile data from LinkedIn after login.
The demo application is from https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

We have to do changes in  "-(RDLinkedInConnectionID *)profileForCurrentUser " this function.
The function is located at LinkedInClientLibrary -> Classes -> RDLinkedInEngine this location.

We just have to change the below url to get data.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[kAPIBaseURL stringByAppendingString:@"/v1/people/~/
"]];
```

To get the user profile data just change the url to:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[kAPIBaseURL stringByAppendingString:@"/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,location:(country:(code)),industry,distance,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,date-of-birth,main-address,positions:(title),educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))"]];
```

From this url we can get the data of the profile user.

To get more fields from user profile refers these links:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/field-selectors
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

To get data according to fields we have to mention the parent of that fields and needed fields from that.This is listed in https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields this link.

If we want data from education so we have to mention as

```
educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities)
```

educations will be the parent and other data in brackets() are its fields which we can get from profile.

Hope this will work with you also.

Comment: from last some hours i am search this things but finally i got the solution from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the above explanation given by Micro is correct ant appropriate

To get the email id from LinkedIn only change the url

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,location:(country:(code)),industry,distance,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,date-of-birth,main-address,positions:(title),educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))"];
```

and you will get the email

or you want more help you can follow the stack overflow link
    [Not able to fetch Linked connections EMAIL ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630267/not-able-to-fetch-linked-connections-email-id/19806450#19806450)