# Not able to fetch Linked connections EMAIL ID

Tags: iphone, ios, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch all the connections of my linkedin account in ios app.

I am able to fetch `id`, `name`, `picture-url` etc. Only thing which is left is email. I am not able to fetch email (`email-address`) of all the connections.

I am using follong code :-

```
    OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope"
                                                                   value:@"r_basicprofile+rw_nus+r_emailaddress"];
    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameParam, nil];
    [request setParameters:params];
    OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" value:@"r_fullprofile rw_nus r_network r_emailaddress"];
    [request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scopeParameter]];
```

and I am fetching connections from

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,Positions)
```

This link return me only `id`, `first-name`, `last-name`, `picture-url` and `Positions`, but NOT `email-address`.

Comment: use this https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client

Comment: I am using the same code, But I want my friend email id

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can't.

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

> "Since the objects returned are of the "person" type you can access
>   any of the Profile Fields available with the r_basicprofile member
>   permission."

The r_basicprofile does not have the **email-address** field in it
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing something wrong with `URL`, please try with below `URL`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,Positions)"];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: And one more this is that make sure you have enable r_emailaddress in your developer account.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by micro is good and appropriate .You can take help from link
      [Fetching user profile data from LinkedIn in iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559518/fetching-user-profile-data-from-linkedin-in-iphone-sdk)

if you are still getting wrong then you can follow link https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client for help it gives you step by step to integrate

But I think for fetching email from LinkedIn you have to do some extra work

I think the url given in sample will not fetch the user email id 
 the look like(https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~)in `OAuthLoginView.m`

please change it with URL  :- 
      http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,location:(country:(code)),industry,distance,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,date-of-birth,main-address,positions:(title),educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))

If you want limited information so please send the parameter which you want.