# iOS iPhone SDK integrating app with instagram

Tags: ios, instagram

Integrating app with instagram.. How it can be done please help thanks in advance
this is the code I have tried

```
 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instagram.jpeg"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savedImagePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",imageUrl);
    UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    docController.delegate = self;
    docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
    docController.URL = imageUrl;
    [docController setURL:imageUrl];
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please read your post and try to understand what's being asked.

Comment: this is the code i have tried ..but its not working can u help?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Rather than just pasting some code, try to tell us what exactly the problem is - *why* doesn't it work, what do you want it to do, where does it go wrong?

Comment: I have to integrate my iphone app with instagram. do u know how it can be done?

Answer (score 4):

Working with the Instagram API in iOS is much more simpler now. Check out this new SDK  http://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [InstagramShareiOS](https://github.com/hiren443/InstagramShareiOS) and [How to share an image on Instagram in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios)

Note that you can't actually post to Instagram via API, you can only check and launch the Instagram app with a image ready to be posted. Instagram hasn't opened their API for posting, and I doubt they will, given that they want to encourage users to (1) use their app and (2) use their filters, auto-adjust, and other features that contribute to the Instagram user experience.

Also, once you leave your app and launch Instagram there's no automatic way of returning,  FWIW.