# IOS: share UIImage in instagram

Tags: ios, uiimage, instagram

In my app I want to share an UIImage means facebook twitter and instagram, for facebook and twitter there aren't problem in IOS 6, but I don't have idea how to share this UIImage with instagram; I have only found a solution: open instagram app and pass this UIImage to it.
Have you other solutions?

Comment: have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios

Comment: http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/# check this please may be this will help and **also** check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

ShareKit makes it pretty easy to share images on Instagram and other social sites.

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit