# Instagram framework for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, instagram

I want to share images to social accounts.

I am able to do for Facebook & Twitter following tutorial at below link.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/

Is there pre-defined framework for Instagram too?

My client is insisting, while sharing the photo you should not go away from the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Instagram API does not support posting images from anything other than the official Instagram app.

Comment: what? I see this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/11501350/1066828, but this is going away from our app...

Comment: That's because the only way to post an image to Instagram is through their app. You cannot do it via the Instagram API. There are no public API endpoints for posting an image via the API.