# How to share Image in Instagram from one application

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

I am trying to share an image on the Instagram application through my application.

Please check my code below and please let me know where I have gone wrong.

```
_instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"instagram://media?id=%@",[SingletoneClass sharedSingleTone].imageId]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:_instagramURL]) {
    self.dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[SingletoneClass sharedSingleTone].imagePath]];
    self.dic.delegate = self;
    self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[SingletoneClass sharedSingleTone].captionStr forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES ];
}
else {
    UIAlertController *alert = [[SingletoneClass sharedSingleTone] setAlertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Instagram is not present in your device" andCallback:^(id actionResponse) {
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If above code is correct, then please let me know, from where I can find the imageId?

Comment: Can you add description about SingletonClass file. What object does it return.

Comment: @AnilGupta are you asking about, 
UIAlertController *alert = [[SingletoneClass sharedSingleTone] setAlertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Instagram is not present in your device" andCallback:^(id actionResponse) {
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

Comment: If you are sharing image from Photo Gallary or Images assets than simply pass the image object path into "_instagramURL". You can find imges ID from https://www.instagram.com/developer/ by registering you applcation. But for sharing you dont need to register you application.

Comment: you find link for sharing image from iOS application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios

Comment: @AnilGupta, i have already gone through this link. I got the action sheet, where i choose copy to Instagram. after that nothing happened. 

May be i am missing something.

Comment: from where did u get this above reference code? can you share Singlton Class file.

Comment: For the swift you can follow link. Its work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337490/how-to-share-image-in-instagramswift

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got the solution. We need to save the image in Document directory. Instagram app can retrieve the image from Document directory.

```
NSData *imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insta.igo"]]; //add our image to the path
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imagedata attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)
```

Then by using UIDocumentInteractionController, we can share the image in Instagram app. 
Before sharing the image, you need to be sure that Instagram app is present in the device.

```
- (void) shareImageToInstagram {
    _instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"instagram://app"]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:_instagramURL])   
    {
        self.dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[SingletoneClass sharedSingleTone].imagePath]];
        self.dic.delegate = self;
        self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
        self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[SingletoneClass sharedSingleTone].captionStr,@"InstagramCaption", nil];
        [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES ];
    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertController *alert = [[SingletoneClass sharedSingleTone] setAlertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Instagram is not present in your device" andCallback:^(id actionResponse) {
            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

You can refer the following links for more information.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/
and [Share photo to Instagram from my iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297157/share-photo-to-instagram-from-my-ios-app)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is inside singleton class? Please upload complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code for share image on Instagram , its working fine

## import

-(void)shareImageOnInstagram:(UIImage *)image {
    if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://"]]) {
        //Your device doesn't have Instagram app.
        return;
    }

```
    //__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    __block PHFetchResult *photosAsset;
    __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder;
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest* createAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
        placeholder = [createAssetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];
        photosAsset = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[placeholder.localIdentifier] options:nil];

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
            requestOptions.synchronous = YES;
            PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
            allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];

            NSString *identifier = placeholder.localIdentifier;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=%@",identifier]];

            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                }];
            }
            });
        }
    }];
```

}