# Instagram Auto Post or One touch share in IOS by third party app

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, instagram, instagram-api

In my app i have to **share image with text on Instagram without opening the Instagram app**. I want to share it on a single touch. I found this 2 year old thread [How to share an image on Instagram in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios).

But it's saying that we have to open the Instagram.

So, is it possible to share the image on Instagram in background or one click by user without open UIDocumentInteractionController?
Looking for best solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems that the linked question describe the only ways of doing it according to: http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Comment: yeah! It is only showing the way of doing with UIDocumentInteractionController. this means it is not possible to direct share right?@Larme

Comment: It seems so. You could maybe use a custom WebService which could do the post from a personal server of yours, but this seems quite extreme.

Comment: what is the process to get private api of Instagram? if you know please tell me @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ways that iOS gives you will present the Instagram UI in some form – Apple doesn’t want malicious apps to be able to post without the user’s consent. This is the same for sending emails, SMS messages and more.

So, the next option is to talk to Instagram servers directly in some way.

From the [Instagram API documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/):

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> 1. Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>      from within the app.
> 2. We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once
>      we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what
>      comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working
>      on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience
>      on our platform.

The other option is reverse engineering. This will probably be painful, will be against the terms of service, will probably stop working at some point, and will make Instagram mad at you. I found this blog post of someone who appears to have done it, but I haven’t tested it, and do not recommend you do this. (Good learning experience though)

http://lancenewman.me/posting-a-photo-to-instagram-without-a-phone/