# Instagram iOS hooks getting the posted media id back

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

My iOS app is using the Instagram iOS hooks to post photos..
It works great and no issues over there.
My Question is: Can I get the posted Media Id back from Instagram?
Let me know if you need any further explanation here. Thx

Comment: Hi guys - any inputs here. I am looking for the Instagram Media/Post Id here..Thx

Comment: Any solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. I have done a lot of research but i didn't find any solution. So there is no way we can get back the Media Id. May be in future Instagram provide such solution, but currently there is no way to do so via programming in Mobile App.