# How to share image on Instagram on iOS

Tags: objective-c, instagram

Today I have faced one difficult problem. I want to share an image on Instagram, but I don't want to open the [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram) app. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No there is not.  Their API does not currently support this.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [API documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) of Instagram you'll see that you can only post images there using the so called `UIDocumentInteractionController`, which means that their app will be opened in the end.

If you still want to share images there, then you should take a look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios) about how to post images to Instagram.

Comment: I understand that, but seemingly Instagram isn't giving you such an option