# Post image on Instagram using Swift (need to translate code)

Tags: ios, image, swift, post, instagram

I found this code in another user question, but its objective-c and i need it in Swift. I tried to translate it, but when the apple share dialog appears and i touch Instagram, the application crashes.

The code is this one: from [How to share an image on Instagram in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios)

```
UIImage *screenShot = finalImage;

NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.igo"];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.igo"];
NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

self.dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Enter your caption here" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {

    [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];

} else {

    NSLog(@"No Instagram Found");
}
```

Of course, in the example the user uses finalImage to declare the screenShot UIImage, so i simply did this to try: (i have an asset called posteo-01 in the project)

```
func postImage() {
    var imagePost = UIImage(named: "posteo-01")
    var savePath = documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Test.igo")
    UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagePost, 100).writeToFile(savePath, atomically: true)
    var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    var igImageHookFile = NSURL(string: "file://\(savePath)")
    var dic = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: igImageHookFile!)
    dic.UTI = "com.instagram.photo"
    dic.annotation = ["InstagramCaption": "hola"]
    dic.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(rect, inView: self.view, animated: true)
    var instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID")

    if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {
        dic.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(rect, inView: self.view, animated: true)
    } else {
        println("no instagram found")
    }

}
func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    return documentsFolderPath
}
```

Thanks!

Already solve it:

```
var docController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

func postImage2() {
    var instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")

    if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {
        var imagePost = UIImage(named: "posteo-01")
        var fullPath = documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("insta.igo")
        var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePost).writeToFile(fullPath, atomically: true)
        var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.docController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
        var igImageHookFile = NSURL(string: "file://\(fullPath)")
        self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: igImageHookFile!)
        self.docController.annotation = ["InstagramCaption":"Text"]
        self.docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(rect, inView: self.view, animated: true)

    } else {
        println("no instagram found")
    }

}

func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    return documentsFolderPath
}
```

Comment: sorry about that, actually doesnt seem to change anything, if i touch facebook in the apple dialog, facebook show me the image :s but instagram crashes

Comment: What is the crash? Where does it crash?

Comment: when i touch the Instagram icon in the apple's share dialog

Comment: I'm talking about in the code.

Comment: I tryed to declare the UIDocumentInteractionController outside the function, it worked! Thanks