# Instagram Sharing button for iOS 9 & 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram-api

I am new to Programing, I've programed an iOS app which is almost completed, Now I want to integrate contents(Image, Text and URL) sharing capability to my app, I've achieved Facebook and Twitter Sharing functionality, But I am stuck at Instagram sharing functionality since two days. 
I've studied lots of material(earlier asked question here [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios), also tried [MGInstagram](https://github.com/mglagola/MGInstagram) and few other third party API's) but all of those are outdated & not working on iOS9 & iOS10, 
I tried to achieve some help from [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) site but there too I am not cleared.

Can Anyone Define some easy way to integrate Instagram Sharing button code in my iOS app also to define authentication process from Instagram site clearly like as tokens & other permissions required for developers.

Thanks

Comment: Check out this link https://cocoapods.org/pods/instagram-ios-sdk

Comment: was checking that specified link, I'll acquire client ID from instagram but can you please share me actual code for button pressed event when I press my button it share a picture some text & URL for my app to the Instagram

Comment: Well I had worked on a sample project which gets the json response from instagram and and shows the latest instagram photo of the user in the imageView if you want I can upload it to Github and you can review the project

Comment: No Thanks, that's not concerned with my question.

Comment: I am still working on it, & Hopefully will be having answer of my required question within next few hours or till a day, 
Once Done, I'll upload my code to here in answer section.
Or if you or anyone else can find any absolute solution, that response will be highly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your Desired question for iOS 9 and 10 So I am explaining for both. 
I am using Instagram,s Standard Documentation API as defined in [iPhone Hooks](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) at Instagram

**Step1:**

open your info.plist file and add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and add your URL schemes which you are going to call in your `canOpenURL` like this.
It is also defined in  [WWDC 2015 Session 703](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/) by *kitty scatter*.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

It will open instargram app installed in your device.

**note** It'll never work in your simulator because of unavailability of required app.

**Step2:**

in your .h file where your `@interface` line ends add this `<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>` to the same `@interface` line

**Step3:**

add following code for sharing image in your instagram sharing button's action

```
// This is your Image you want to share. you can write 
 UIImage *image = imageView.image;

 //Add this line of code instead of doing step One if you are at early version of iOS9 till iOS 9.2.3  but if you are using iOS9.5 or above like as iOS10 not use this line and do step1 instead of writing this line of code   
  NSURL *instagram = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];



 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagram]) {

    //convert image into .png format.
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    //create instance of NSFileManager
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //add our image to the path
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insta.igo"]];

    //finally save the path (image)
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSString *fileNameToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/insta.igo"];
    NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameToSave];
    NSLog(@"jpg path %@",jpgPath);

    NSString *newJpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath];
    NSLog(@"with File path %@",newJpgPath);

   // NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:newJpgPath];

    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [NSURL URLWithString:newJpgPath];

    NSLog(@"url Path %@",igImageHookFile);

    UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
     documentController.delegate = self;
    [documentController setUTI:@"com.instagram.exclusivegram"];
    [documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];

} else {
   // NSLog (@"Instagram not found");
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Install Instagram"
                                                                   message:@" Before Sharing to Instagram, Please Install Instagram app to your Device. "
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Thanks" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:nil];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**Final Note:** 
Follow Step one if you are using iOS SDK 9.5 or above like 10. and to remove second line of code mentioned in third step. and in case you are using iOS 9 till 9.2.3 then no needs to do first step, you should follow second line of code of third step.

Hope it'll work smoothly like water flow. . . :)

Comment: Let me try for that, I'll be back shortly.

Comment: I tried to mark it up, a popup message telling me that I needs at least 15 reputations to mark as up. so simply I approved Accepted. 
Thanks

Comment: @MDIbrahim_Hassan, `canOpenUrl` never works in your simulator, It'll only work in your Device, also did you configured your **plist** file as I Mentioned above in **step1**  for iOS plist file configuration. there'll be url strings but you've to add that one for instagram. Please read step1 carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This should open instagram on a device and share the photo onto Instagram.

```
  - (IBAction)imageShareToInsta:(id)sender {
        NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image.igo", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject]];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
        UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
        docController.delegate=self;
        docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
        [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view  animated:YES];   
    }
```

Declare `<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>`in your ViewController.h file
Hope it helps you out.

Comment: but only on device not simulator coz it requires instagram installed. Test it out and  then accept my answer

Comment: from where did you copied that? can you send me some reference ?

Comment: I just remodelled the code from my previous project which I used for Instagram api. Well here is working screen cast from the actual device https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5S4rNisN4tU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: there is two Errors. one in         `[UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];` where `self.imageView.image` should be like this `cell.imageView.image` which I corrected.,

yet there is another issue in following line `docController.delegate=self;` saying that **assigning to 'id<UIDocumentinteractionController> _nulable' from incompatible type DetailTableView**   where DetailTableView is my viewController's Name so please suggest how to remove this issue, I tried my best but could not succeeded .. . .

Comment: by declaring `<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>` in .h file that issue is also removed. now testing.

Comment: Sorry it does not giving desired result.  Yet Highly Appreciating for your time & attention.