# Share image with hashtag via UIActivityViewController (Twitter, Facebook, Instagram)

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to share an image with a hashtag using UIActivityViewController and I am encountering some strange behavior when attempting to share to Twitter, Facebook and Instagram. There does not seem to be a lot of documentation about these service's share extensions.

**Scenario 1: Init controller with activity item array with image and text**

If I initialize the controller like so, Twitter and Facebook will show up in the controller (no Instagram as it does not support text items), and both will programmatically pre-populate the hashtag in the text entry field:

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myHashtagString, myImage], applicationActivities: nil)
```

**Scenario 2: Init controller with only image**

In this scenario, all networks show up, but I (obviously) lose the automatic hashtag feature:

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myImage], applicationActivities: nil)
```

**Scenario 3: UIActivityItemSource subclass**

If I make my own UIActivityItemSource subclass, I can almost get everything to work. However, and this is what I cannot figure out, using the protocol methods as I have below results in the automatic hashtag working for Facebook, but not Twitter. How can this be possible -- is there a special key needed for Twitter? There must be a way for it to work if it works in Scenario #1...

Interestingly, this method works for both Twitter and Facebook if I insert a URL (commented out). So why on earth won't the text work for Twitter!?

```
let activityItem = CustomItemSource(image: image, message: "#TestTag")
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

...

class CustomItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

    private var image: UIImage!
    private var message: String!

    // MARK: Init
    init(image: UIImage, message: String) {
        super.init()

        self.image = image
        self.message = message
    }

    // MARK: Item Source Protocol
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return image
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        if activityType == .postToTwitter || activityType == .postToFacebook {
            //return ["url": URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!, "image": image]

            return ["text": message, "image": image]
        }
        else {
            return ["image": image]
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Define two `UIActivityItemSource` classes, one for *Image* and one for *Text*.

In first one only return the image.
In second one return `NSObject()` for placeHolder, and return `Text` or `nil` depending on activity. By returning `NSObject()`, UIActivity will allow all services to be available.

```
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [ImageProvider(), TextProvider()], applicationActivities: nil)
```

and providers:

```
class TextProvider: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return NSObject()
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        if activityType == .postToTwitter || activityType == .postToFacebook {
            return "Tweet with #Hashtag"
        }
        return nil
    }
}

class ImageProvider: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return UIImage(named: ...)
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        return UIImage(named: ...)
    }
}
```

## Explaination

First of all, Keys are not really sensitive, The only sensitive-key was "subject" for email and apps supporting it, which is implemented in `UIActivityController`'s API and we can set it directly. It doesn't matter if you provide `UIImage` with key "image" or "1".

As it turns out, Twitter activity will not work if it's text is not returned ***directly*** in `...itemForActivity...` method. So the solution is to separate item sources.

Twitter activity also will not work, if `placeholder` receives anything other than `String`, but by returning `String` Instagram activity will not work, So by returning `NSObject()` Type will be ignored and all services will be available.
if you want to limit some services use `UIActivityViewController.excludedActivityTypes`

Comment: Excellent, never would have thought to return NSObject!

Comment: @DerrickHunt Unfortunately, It doesn't make sense at all ... found it with try and error.

Comment: Does this solution enable posting on Instagram with hashtag?

Comment: @guneykayim unfortunately, instagram does not support text by uiactivity. You should use UIDocumentInteractionController. Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Genius.

Comment: @farzadshbfn I want to share image in Instagram using UIActivityController.

Please help me.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya with or without text? I assume u’re saying with text because my solution works without text (unless it’s broken in ios versions). Have u read the other threat i’ce mentioned in comments?

Comment: @EktaPadaliya My solution is not working for you? what's the blocker?

Comment: any objective c version? :(

Comment: @Reza.Ab It doesn't use any advanced swift technologies, with correct function naming and all, you can easily convert it to obj-c.  If you had any problems contact me through farzad.shbfn@gmail.com

Comment: Doesn't work at all - the share view is shown but it is empty