# Sharing PNG image with UIActivityViewController to Facebook Messenger always fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, messenger

This is a question for an expert with specialist knowledge.

It is possible to successfully share high quality lossless `PNG` images with `UIActivityViewController` to many sharing platforms with the exception of Facebook Messenger which fails every time. The error provided is `“Couldn’t Load Content”`.

Both `UIImagePNGRepresentation` `NSData` and `AnyObject` fail in Facebook Messenger, `UIImage` however shares successfully *BUT* the outputted image appears to be a JPG and is low quality and lossy.

**Question:**

What’s going on here and how can it be corrected -- how can I successfully share high quality lossless PNG images with `UIActivityViewController` to Facebook Messenger?

Is this a problem or limitation of Facebook Messenger, Xcode, or `UIActivityViewController`?

Are there alternatives to `NSData` and `AnyObject` (and  `UIImage`) that will work?

**Code:**

```
var myImage: UIImage! 
var myImagePNG: NSData! 
//var myImagePNG: AnyObject!

func sharePNG() { …
    myImagePNG = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage)!
    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myImagePNG], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do?You shoud use `myImage` instead of `myImagePNG`.

Comment: @Codus, thanks but I think you need to reread the question. `myImage` gives lossy low quality image output. `myImagePNG` gives a lossless high quality image output when sharing with all apps except for Messenger which fails. I'm after lossless high quality image output when sharing to Messenger, that's what I want to do. I want to use `myImagePNG` like I successfully do when sharing to all other apps.

Comment: I have the same issue. Only occurs when sharing to Facebook Messenger. Did you find a solution already?

Comment: @codeDude sorry for the delay in reply. Unfortunately no, a solution was not found. I resigned to the fact Facebook Messenger currently does not cooperate with iOS sharing. The lossy image remains when sharing. If that's what Facebook Messenger wants, that's what Facebook Messenger gets, lossy images. :-)

Comment: Further @codeDude , on a related question, this might point to some sort of solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380570/share-image-with-hashtag-via-uiactivityviewcontroller-twitter-facebook-instag

Comment: @user4806509 Thanks for shedding some light on the matter. Hehe, yea it is their loss....lossy images

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get more control over what gets shared from UIActivityController is not just to encode it to data, but then to write that data to a temporary URL, and then pass the URL to UIActivityController. That way you can control the title of the file being shared, which is important if they choose to save the file or AirDrop it somewhere. If you just share the data you'll end up with some really random filename. This works for sending PNGs via Facebook Messenger:

```swift
    enum ImageProcessingError: Error {
        case couldNotCreatePNGData
    }
    
    private func exportImageAsPNG(_ image: UIImage, filename: String) throws {
        guard let pngData = image.pngData() else { throw ImageProcessingError.couldNotCreatePNGData }
        let temporaryURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
            .appendingPathComponent(filename)
            .appendingPathExtension("png")
        try pngData.write(to: temporaryURL, options: [])
        // present UIActivityViewController with the temporaryURL
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to keep the quality of the images try using  `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`

Comment: Thanks. I already use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` and then `drawViewHierarchyInRect` to capture. The capture is perfect quality. It's actually at the point of sharing when things go odd with Messenger.