# Sharing to Instagram does not work using the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivityitemprovider

I share text and an image using the `UIActivityViewController`. The image is from `activityImage` which is an `UIImage()`. The custom text is from `activityText()` which is returned from an `UIActivityItemSource` protocol.

The trouble is, Instagram is only visible in the `UIActivityViewController` under certain conditions.

To summerize the tests below:

- Instagram is only **visible** in the `UIActivityViewController` for `activityItems: [activityImage]` and `activityItems: [activityImage, NSNull()]`
- Instagram is **hidden** for `activityItems: [activityImage, activityText()]` even when the returned `UIActivityItemSource` protocol value is `""`, `nil`, `NSNull()`.

The issue is that the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol needs to be called so that different sharing platforms can be managed separately.

---

> **Questions:**
>
> - How can I share to Instagram when calling the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol?
> - What are the alternatives to `""`, `nil` and `NSNull()` that I could try when calling the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol?

---

**Code:**

```
class activityText: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return ""
    }
    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        switch activityType {
        case UIActivityTypeMessage:
            return "Special text when sharing to Messages."
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
}

func shareEverwhere() {
      var activityImage: UIImage() 
      let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage, activityText()], applicationActivities: nil)
      self.presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

**Tests:**

Instagram is **visible** in the `UIActivityViewController`

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage], applicationActivities: nil)
```

or

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage, NSNull()], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Instagram is **hidden** in the `UIActivityViewController`

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage, ""], applicationActivities: nil)
```

or

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage, activityText()], applicationActivities: nil)
```

or

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage, activityText()], applicationActivities: nil)
class activityText: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return ""
    }
    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return NSNull()
    }
}
```

or

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage, activityText()], applicationActivities: nil)
class activityText: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return ""
    }
    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
            return nil
    }
}
```

or

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage, activityText()], applicationActivities: nil)
class activityText: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return ""
    }
    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
            return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The question was asked and answered at: [Share image with hashtag via UIActivityViewController (Twitter, Facebook, Instagram)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380570/share-image-with-hashtag-via-uiactivityviewcontroller-twitter-facebook-instag)

```
        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
 [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[vm.image, [[ActivityStringItemSource alloc] initWithString:attributedString]] applicationActivities:nil];
```

And the class that implements the return of the string (or not) is:

```
@interface ActivityStringItemSource()<UIActivityItemSource>

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableAttributedString *stringContent;
@end

@implementation ActivityStringItemSource

- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSMutableAttributedString *) placeholder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _stringContent = placeholder;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return [NSObject new];
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(UIActivityType)activityType {
    if([activityType containsString:@"instagram"]) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return _stringContent;
    }
}

@end
```

The key, as pointed by the original answer is to return an NSObject (the class extends NSObject). Then in the item selection, just test instagram to return nil and otherwise return your string.

Comment: Thanks @Olivier Brand , I will check this out and give it a go.

Comment: Could you explain more?!

Answer (score 0):

After testing only you have to do is add your image to activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem

```
final class MyImageItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

    final let image: UIImage

    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        image
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        image
    }

}
```