# Xamarin Forms iOS Share Instagram Photo doesn't work

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, share

I can't share an image to Instagram, I don't know why.

I'm working with Xamarin Forms, and I'm trying to share an image to Instagram, using DependencyService to allow to call a function in the Project.iOS

**I'm testing the app on the ios emulator**

First of all, I try to obtain an UIImage from an Uri:

uri = https://oc.ocstatic.com/images/favicon/android-chrome-512x512.png

```
public static UIImage FromUrl(string uri)
                    {
                        var imageName = uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(NativeImagesPath, imageName)))
                            return UIImage.FromFile(Path.Combine(NativeImagesPath, imageName));

                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(ImagesCachePath, imageName)))
                            return UIImage.FromFile(Path.Combine(ImagesCachePath, imageName));

                        if (Items.ContainsKey(uri))
                            return Items[uri];

                        using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
                        using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
                        {
                            var image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);

                            if (!NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(ImagesCachePath))
                                NSFileManager.DefaultManager.CreateDirectory(ImagesCachePath, false, null);

                            var result = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.CreateFile(Path.Combine(ImagesCachePath, imageName), data, new NSFileAttributes());
                            if (!result)
                                Items[uri] = image;

                            return image;
                        }
                    }
```

And then, I want to share this UIImage to Instagram using this code below:

`````
var imageURL = FromUrl(path);
NSString documentDirectory = (new NSString(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)));
                string saveImagePath = documentDirectory.AppendPathComponent(new NSString(@"Image.ig"));
NSData imageData = imageURL.AsPNG();
imageData.Save(saveImagePath, true);
NSUrl imageURLfinal = NSUrl.FromFilename(saveImagePath);

if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(instagramURL)) {

UIDocumentInteractionController DocumentController = new UIDocumentInteractionController();
DocumentController.Delegate = new UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass(this);
DocumentController.Url = imageURLfinal;
DocumentController.Uti = "com.instagram.photo";

DocumentController.PresentOpenInMenu(new RectangleF(1, 1, 1, 1), this.View, true);

  returnMessage = "NSURL: " + path;
}
else
{
  returnMessage = "Instagram Not Found";
}
````

I expect the Instagram screen.
`````

Comment: Have you tried using "com.instagram.exlusivegram" this Uti ?

Comment: Yes, but nothing :(

Comment: Maybe, It can be by running it on the emulator???

Comment: Check if you already have Instagram app installed on the device. It does not open otherwise

Comment: I only open Instagram, but I haven't the photo to post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393071/how-to-share-an-image-on-instagram-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also put the question on Xamarin Forums and I have just post the solution at the problem for me here.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/386163#Comment_386163